# Did Gigi Wu ("bikini climber") die of hypothermia because she was only wearing a bikini?

Tags: sport, clothing, taiwan

[Example claim](https://www.facebook.com/waltonandjohnson/posts/10156176932893473) from a verified Facebook user:

> So you're saying we shouldn't walk around on top of steep mountains while wearing bikinis?
>
> https://kprcradio.iheart.com/featured/the-pursuit-of-happiness/content/2019-01-22-bikini-climber-freezes-to-death-after-65-foot-fall-off-mountain/?fbclid=IwAR3ABoClJ8gBdpeLlLB1n5PGbOXS15Y2MS0khq2Mk4alvhQh_TlUPyGlNnQ
>
> 'Bikini Climber' Freezes To Death After 65-Foot Fall Off Mountain

Plus some sample responses:

> [Natural selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_selection)
>
> Probably some "Bikini-Mountain Challenge," or some such crap. [Presumably a reference to the [Bird Box Challenge](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-01-03/netflix-urges-fans-to-not-do-bird-box-challenge/10681770)]
>
> Attention whoring has taken another life.
>
> Being so young and pretty, the probably thought she was invincible like most people do at that age. Unfortunately, the ignorance and stupidity of young adults often costs the their health or their lives.

Example tweets from news organisations on Twitter: [Daily Mirror](https://twitter.com/DailyMirror/status/1087294990852583424)

> 'Bikini hiker' who climbed mountains in barely-there swimwear freezes to death https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/bikini-hiker-who-climbed-mountains-13886021

and [ALT 98.7](https://twitter.com/ALT987fm/status/1087990649163603969):

> Woman Known as the Bikini Hiker Falls Down Ravine and Freezes to Death
>
> Who would've guess "bikini" wasn't high up on the hiking gear list?

The Twitter Moment [Gigi Wu, who was also known as the “Bikini hiker,” fell into a ravine at the Yushan national park in Taiwan and froze to death as a result.](https://twitter.com/TwitterMoments/status/1087669427800367104) didn't state that she died because she was wearing a bikini, but did little to dispel that impression.

Did Gigi Wu die of hypothermia because she was only wearing a bikini?

Comment: The bikini may or may not have played a role, but falling 65 feet off a mountain isn't going to leave *anyone* in good health no matter what they're wearing, with the possible exception of a parasail.

Comment: Simple proof:  She was able to call for help after falling.  I'm not aware of any satellite communications system small enough to be hidden in a bikini.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Even the linked article ['Bikini Climber' Freezes To Death After 65-Foot Fall Off Mountain](https://kprcradio.iheart.com/featured/the-pursuit-of-happiness/content/2019-01-22-bikini-climber-freezes-to-death-after-65-foot-fall-off-mountain/?fbclid=IwAR3ABoClJ8gBdpeLlLB1n5PGbOXS15Y2MS0khq2Mk4alvhQh_TlUPyGlNnQ) indicates Wu wore a regular amount of clothing until she posed for photos:

> While photos usually showed Wu in a bikini, she was an experienced hiker and wore **proper climbing gear** until it was time for her pictures to be taken.

The article also notes that she was on a long hike going over multiple days and nights, rather than a short sprint up and down the mountain:

> Wu was taking part in a 25-day hike on Taiwan's Yushan Mountain when she fell down a ravine.

The details of her death seem rather mundane, involving a severe fall, injuries, bad weather and rescue crews being unable to rescue her. And that she was fully clothed and also had an aluminium blanket on.

From [Taiwan's 'bikini hiker' dies after falling into ravine on solo trek](https://www.smh.com.au/world/asia/taiwans-bikini-hiker-dies-after-falling-into-ravine-on-solo-trek-20190123-p50t5e.html), published in the Sydney Morning Herald but from The Washington Post:

> The 36-year-old woman was in the middle of a solo hiking trip in
>   Yushan National Park when she fell more than 65 feet into a ravine on
>   Saturday, Apple Daily News reported.
>
> Even after she fell, Wu was able to use a satellite phone to call
>   friends and give her coordinates, Nantou County fire official Lin
>   Cheng-yi told reporters. However, the situation was dire: Wu
>   reportedly also told her friends that she couldn't move the lower half
>   of her body.
>
> Because of poor weather conditions, rescuers had to try to reach Wu on
>   foot. It wouldn't be until noon Monday - about 43 hours after Wu's
>   distress call - that rescuers discovered her body, Lin said. By then,
>   it was too late. A cause of death was not immediately confirmed.
>
> Photos obtained by TVBS News showed an array of hiking gear scattered
>   across a forest floor, reportedly near where Wu had fallen. Rescuers
>   told the news station that Wu had been found fully clothed, covered in
>   an aluminum blanket and with a flashlight wrapped around one hand.

The article also mentions her usual precautions:

> In interviews, she said she hiked with proper gear and clothing, only
>   changing into a bikini when reaching the top of a peak.
>
> In a May 2017 post, she wrote that she had no option but to turn back
>   during one portion of a hike and that it was important to be extra
>   cautious when hiking solo.
>
> "Even a slight wrong can be your last," she wrote then.

Comment: I think it's worth highlighting that she was fully clothed when the rescuers found her. It's certainly relevant that she *typically* wore appropriate climbing gear when not taking photos, but I think that knowing about the *specific* case is even more important.

Comment: It's probably also worth highlighting that "a cause of death was not immediately confirmed" in the face of the claims that she "froze to death."  It's not at all clear that she died of hypothermia.